# VB.net / SQL Adding Data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My question is somewhat complex but simple. I am building a small program to keep track of inventory. I created a view that contains a list of names and id in SQL. I then created a table so that I can add items to the names in SQL

IN vb.net 
When the users clicks on the 1st datagridview - the name and number comes in separate text boxes. When they click the save button the records will then get saved to my table. (Which I have another Datagridview to show names and items. ) When I click my save button I get the following error:
 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Inventory_Detail'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Inventory_Detail'. The duplicate key value is (4         ).
I initially had the foreign key but then dropped based on the error but I am still getting it????

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1


    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=Inventory;User ID=;Password=")
    Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT res_snbr, res_First_Name, res_Last_Name FROM ResidentInventoryView", cn)
    Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adap)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim res_snbr As Object

    'Dim InventoryDetailsBindingSource As New BindingSource

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        ' DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        '  DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
        DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
        '
        adap.Fill(dt)
        ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource


    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
            ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("res_First_Name Like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
        Else
            ResidentInventoryViewBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Try
            adap.Update(dt)
            MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error updating database")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Me.rlastname.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        Me.rfname.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
        Me.rnum.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value



    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        cn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("Insert INTO Inventory_Detail Values('" & _
                                  rnum.Text & "','" & _
                                  rfname.Text & "','" & _
                                  rnum.Text & "','" & _
                                  txtitem.Text & "','" & _
                                  "" & "','" & _
                                  "" & "')"), cn)





        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

        MsgBox("Success....", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")

        rnum.Clear()
        rfname.Clear()
        rnum.Clear()
        txtitem.Clear()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should not be inserting index values into a `Primary/Unique Key` field where unique is set to `True`.

Comment: @jbarker2160 a primary key MUST have a value. I think you are assuming that all primary keys are identity. This may or may not be true but your comment is not correct.

Comment: @SeanLange, so you know of another way to get that error?

Comment: You need to look at sql injection. What you posted here is wide open. Add some parameters to those queries so you don't end up on the front page of the nightly news.

Comment: Sure, it happens when you try to insert duplicate values into a column that doesn't allow duplicates. That doesn't mean you shouldn't provide a value.

Comment: @SeanLange, if you're providing your own values(unless it's a GUID) for such a column you'll last about 5 minutes on my team(just fired a guy this week for something very similar after 2 days on the job.)  That's not a best practice and a terrible way to develop.

Comment: LOL I didn't say it was the best approach but if the primary key is natural I would argue that some silly arbitrary identity is useless.

Comment: I guess there isnt perhaps a way to allow the datagrid to edit views? You cant edit datagrids unless there is a primary key

Comment: The INSERT statement will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an item in the `Inventory_Detail` table with the id of 4. You need to increment the id so that every record in the `Inventory_Detail` table has a unique id.

You can you the `Identity` property in SQL to Increment your Primary Key so you don't have to insert the id manually.
[Identity MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186775.aspx)

Or Consider using a `GUID` that way it is always unique.

Comment: GUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique and they are awful as the clustered index because the index fragmentation is out of control.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so what I did ( maybe not the best)

created a view to get all names and ids

Created one table - contains a primary key that auto Increments 
has an id field 
item 
start date
end date

The above will allow one person to be assigned multiple items and keep track of the items

Comment: The only bad thing on my layout is that the items and people move around so i will have to track that. I guess I will create another view for my second date grid :( which will have to link to the same text boxes for change